# Need help understanding RewriteRule to make 404 return a default file instead of 404

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a rule (that works). It checks if a .png file returns a 404.  If so, it sends a default png image file.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.png /sites/all/libraries/somefolder/404.png [L]
```

I would like this to only look inside a specific folder (instead of matching every .png).  I tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^/sites/all/libraries/somefolder/(.*)\.png /sites/all/libraries/somefolder/404.png [L]
```

But it does not work.  What is wrong with that?

Comment: Try `RewriteRule ^sites/all/libraries/somefolder/(.*)\.png /sites/all/libraries/somefolder/404.png [L]`

Answer (score 0):

Do not do this with only `more_rewrite`. It's good that you want to provide an appropriate content type, but doing it as you've suggested, and @anubhava's commented, will still return a `200 OK` response.

Instead, set the `ErrorDocument 404 …` to point to, and/or deliberately redirect such requests to a 404 script, e.g. in php. This script should set the 404 status header, then just read out a file of a content type based on the `Accept` header sent with the request, you'll probably only need 3 types, plain text, html, and the `404.png` for images.